# Is there a text book containing a self-contained and complete proof of the Jordan Curve theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I seem to remember (in my undergraduate years) encountering a book on complex analysis which contained a proof of the Jordan Curve Theorem, building up from first principles - so self-contained and complete. I am now looking for such a proof, and haven't been able to find one. Does anyone know of such a book, or alternatively an online resource which starts at the beginning and finishes at the end? The level I'm looking for is roughly a demanding first course in complex analysis.

---

Edit: Does Beardon's book "Complex Analysis: The Argument Principle in Analysis and Topology" do this? I can't find a review or synopsis.

Comment: What proof methods did it use? "Introduction to the theory of functions of a complex variable" by Wolfgang J. Thron has a proof of Jordan's Curve theorem. However, it does not use any homology and is quite complicated to follow. From what I can see by glancing at it, no essential complex analysis is used either.

Comment: A comment ten years late: yes, there is a proof of Jordan curve theorem in sec. 11.4 of Beardon‘s *Complex Analysis*.

Comment: @RamenNii-chan I think that is the one I was thinking of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I found the following resources:

1. https://luisto.fi/misc.shtml Click on "[An essay about the jordan curve theorem](http://luisto.fi/documents/JordanCurveTheorem.pdf)". It is in the spirit of complex analysis.
2. "Introduction to the theory of functions of a complex variable" by Wolfgang J. Thron.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Munkres Topology textbook contains such a proof. Downside is that it doesn't take an approach through complex analysis.